# Как использовать holder.js в React

Tags: веб-программирование, reactjs

Я добавил через npm модуль holderjs

```
npm install holderjs
```

но теперь не знаю как его использовать. В описании пакета написано что необходимо в HTML добавить

```html
<script src="holder.js"></script>
```

однако все равно ничего не работает. Если в компонент импортировать модуль, то он сработает один раз (при загрузке), но после повторного открытия с помощью `Route` (react-router-dom) картинка не загружается.

Код главного компонента

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Workspace from "./components/Workspace";
import NoFound from "./components/NoFound";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>
                        <Home/>  //<---тут находится картинка
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/workspace'>
                        <Workspace/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route>
                        <NoFound/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Внутренний компонент

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../styles/styles.css';
import {Carousel, Jumbotron} from "react-bootstrap";
import 'holderjs'

class Home extends Component{


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Carousel>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img   //<---Тут картинка, остальное не особо важно
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
                            alt="First slide"
                        />
                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>First slide label</h3>
                            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
                            alt="Third slide"
                        />

                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
                            alt="Third slide"
                        />

                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>
                <div className="position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-light">
                    <Jumbotron>
                        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                        <p>
                            This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling
                            extra attention to featured content or information.
                        </p>
                    </Jumbotron>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

При первом открытии странички картинка загружается, но с `src=data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2F...и много других знаков` но после переключения вкладок (например в другую, а потом вернуться обратно и без перезагрузки) эта ссылка становиться такой же как и в jsx `src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"`и, собственно говоря, по ней ничего нет

Answer (score 0):

Вот проект, который реализует то что нужно https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-holder. Подключаете его в свой проект вместо `holder.js` и вперёд. Если не хотите подключать непопулярную библиотеку, то всегда мож[но посмотреть как она реализов](https://github.com/Moeriki/react-holder/blob/master/src/holder.js)ана и сделать точно так же у себя.

Comment: Я рассматривал этот вариант, но было бы удобней использовать именно holder.js чтобы в коде был именно `<img/>` для изменения src по необходимости.

Comment: Тогда тем более посмотрите на исходный код той библиотеки. Судя по коду, вам нужно будет где-нибудь в `index.js` (или где там у вас делается  `ReactDOM.render`) запустить `holderjs.run()` (вроде бы можно даже без параметров)  ну а дальше создавать `<img>` и готово.

Comment: кстати, может быть ваш вариант и не работает потому что `holderjs.run()` не делается.

Comment: Я посмотрел на методы `holderjs` и методы используются для программного внедрения картинок и настройки темы для holder.js . Метод `run(userObject)` позволяет программно вставить картинку в тег с id который вы там укажите

Comment: Ну тогда свой компонент, сорри, бро. Тем временем, давайте подождём, может кто поумнее нарисуется и что-то нормальное предложит.

Comment: вы, кстати, случайно не из ангуляра в реакт пришли? А то сам реву каждый раз, когда приходится создаывать компоненты там где счастливые люди обходятся атрибутами/директивами.

Comment: нет, я только начал изучать React, нужен для проекта в универе. Нам просто нельзя использовать MVC нужен отдельно back-end, front-end, mobile app (native), IoT и база данных. Вот сижу мучаюсь